# Is 〜であるものか construction allowable?

Tags: grammar, usage, na-adjectives

In 新完全{しんかんぜん}マスター文法{ぶんぽう}N2 page xi the formation rules for 〜ものか are

> 普通形{ふつうけい}（ナ形｛けい｝<s>だ</s>-な・名｛めい｝<s>だ</s>-な）＋ものか

These rules seem to preclude the form 〜であるものか.

There is also this note at the bottom of the same page

> 本書｛ほんしょ｝では、あまり使｛つか｝われない接続｛せつぞく｝のし方｛かた｝は載｛の｝せていません。

Is 〜であるものか form incorrect or is it just less frequently used?

To give concrete examples:
 a) `きれいなものか`,
 b) `きれいであるものか`. 
I fail to feel/understand why b) would be incorrect/unnatural.

Below I give reasons why I think `〜であるものか` might be correct.

1. I found a sentence containing `であるものか` on a Japanese website ([city.seto.aichi.jp](http://www.city.seto.aichi.jp/docs/2016070500065/files/oboyoryo2017.pdf)):

   > 補助金｛ほじょきん｝がなければ実施｛じっし｝が困難｛こんなん｝であるものか。
2. I found in a 国語辞書{こくごじしょ} ([dictionary.goo.ne.jp](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/219799/meaning/m0u/)) that 〜ものか follows a 連体形｛連体形｝:

   > ［終助｛しゅうじょ｝］《連語｛れんご｝「ものか1」から》連体形に付｛つ｝く。

   And I reason that given a 形容動詞, for example きれいだ, I can get a 連体形 in more than one way:

   - `きれいな` - by definition,
   - `きれいである` because it is  `きれいで` (連用形｛れんようけい｝) +  verb `ある` (連体形).

Comment: であるものか is no problem.